# Oh-My-Zsh rails3 plugin aliases fail in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

My rails version is 4.0.0. I'm using `Oh-My-Zsh` and I like it for it's hugh plugin repository and intelligence. However, I've activated the `rails3` plugin which is supposed to give me aliases mentioned in this [oh-my-zsh wiki](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Plugins).
I have tried several of them like `rg`, `rgbm`, `rgbm`, `rs` but all of them shows this error:

```
ruby: No such file or directory -- script/rails (LoadError)
```

Is this an incompatibility error of `rails 4` environment and `rails3` plugin of `oh-my-zsh`? Is there a way to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, the rails wrapper script was moved to the bin directory, so the existing plugin is not compatible